# BitBlt drawing bitmap upside down

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

I have an MFC control to which I pass a handle to a bitmap (HBITMAP). In the controls OnPaint method I am using BitBlt to render the bitmap. But the bitmap is being rendered upside down.

As a test I created a CBitmap object from this handle and write that out to a file and it created a bitmap that was right side up. So am I doing something wrong with my call to BitBlt?

I've posted my code from OnPaint below. I did try to change the mapping mode of my device context to MM_LOENGLISH and was able to get the bitmap to render right side up but it was very grainy. When I leave the mapping mode at MM_TEXT the quality of the image is perfect but as I said it is upside down. I haven't worked much with bitmaps, blitting etc...so I could be missing something easy. Any other suggestions would be appreciated. For some background I'm grabbing a BYTE* from a video camera driver and creating the HBITMAP to render the video.
How can I get this to render properly?? Many thanks

```
void BitmapControl::OnPaint()
{
EnterCriticalSection (&CriticalSection);

if (_handleBMP)
{

    CPaintDC dc(this);
    //dc.SetMapMode(MM_LOENGLISH);
    CDC dcMem;
    dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    dc.DPtoLP(&rect);


    CBitmap* pBmpOld = dcMem.SelectObject(CBitmap::FromHandle(_handleBMP));
    BitBlt(dc,rect.left,rect.top,rect.Width(),rect.Height(),dcMem,rect.left,rect.top,SRCCOPY); //works with MM_TEXT but upsidedown
    //BitBlt(dc,0,rect.bottom,rect.Width(),-rect.Height(),dcMem,0,0,SRCCOPY); //works with MM_LOENGLISH
    dcMem.SelectObject(pBmpOld);
    DeleteDC(dc);
    DeleteDC(dcMem);
    DeleteObject(_handleBMP);
    DeleteObject(pBmpOld);
    _handleBMP = NULL;

}
LeaveCriticalSection (&CriticalSection);
}
```

edit*
I was assuming because I could save the bitmap to disk in the correct orientation that the problem was with bitblt. Here is the code I use to generate the HBITMAP.

```
 HBITMAP BitmapWriter::CreateBitmapFromFrame(BYTE* frame)
{
BITMAPFILEHEADER* bmfh;
bmfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)frame;

BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih = &_bmi;

BITMAPINFO* bmpInfo = (BITMAPINFO*)bmih;

HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBSection(_hdc,bmpInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS,NULL,NULL,0);
SetBitmapBits(hbmp,_bmi.biSizeImage,frame);


return hbmp;
}
```

Oh, and I used the critical section because I pass the hbitmap to the control in a property and then access it in the OnPaint. If that's a potential problem I will have to rethink that. Thanks

Comment: It possibly has more to do with how you created `_handleBMP` than with the way you're drawing it.

Comment: This almost certainly started wrong in the code that created the bitmap.  Beware that the scan lines are stored upside-down.  Btw, EnterCriticalSection is a raw red flag in painting code, GDI is fundamentally not thread-safe.

Answer (score 8):

Windows bitmaps are stored with the bottom line first. Most of the rest of the world works top line first, so I presume that's what you're getting from your camera.

You can use a negative height in the BITMAPINFOHEADER structure to reverse the normal order.

Comment: I changed the biHeight property in the BITMAPINFOHEADER object from 480 to -480 but this had no effect, it is still rendered upside down

Comment: @mash, I hope you understood that I meant to make this change at the place where the bitmap is created from the raw data. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Yes I think I'm setting it to late, I am getting the raw data from a DirectShow graph. My graph consists of a source filter and sample grabber, my sample grabber publishes the raw data to subscribers, one of which is my renderer. I guess I need to somehow set a property for my source filter? I'm not sure how to do this yet

Answer (score 8):

Just use a Negative value in the biHeight field of BITMAPINFOHEADER struct.

```
bi.biHeight = -height;  //this is the line that makes it draw upside down or not
```

Answer (score 1):

In `MM_TEXT` y-axis points down, while in the other mapping modes it points up. Try `MM_ISOTROPIC` mapping mode. For more precise control, you may need to set viewport and window offset and extents on [CDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4acfw2ha%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#_mfc_mapping_functions_cdc).

Bitmaps can be stored upside down, that is indicated by negative height in the [BITMAPINFOHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure, but this should not be a problem.

Comment: You could always just negate the height in the structure, forcing it to draw the other way without modifying the mapping mode.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I seem to have this working. I ended up changing the mapping mode to MM_LOENGLISH. As I said before this gave me a grainy image but this was corrected by adding the following

dc.SetStretchBltMode(COLORONCOLOR);

I need to do a bit of reading to actually figure out why...but here is my rendering code now.

```
void BitmapControl::OnPaint()
{
EnterCriticalSection (&CriticalSection);

if (_handleBMP)
{

    CPaintDC dc(this);
    //dc.SetMapMode(MM_ISOTROPIC);
    dc.SetMapMode(MM_LOENGLISH);
    CDC dcMem;
    dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    dc.DPtoLP(&rect);

    CBitmap* pBmpOld = dcMem.SelectObject(CBitmap::FromHandle(_handleBMP));

    //tst
    dc.SetStretchBltMode(COLORONCOLOR);

    //BitBlt(dc,rect.left,-0,rect.Width(),rect.Height(),dcMem,rect.left,rect.top,SRCCOPY); //works with MM_TEXT but upsidedown
    BitBlt(dc,0,rect.bottom,rect.Width(),-rect.Height(),dcMem,0,0,SRCCOPY); //works with MM_LOENGLISH
    dcMem.SelectObject(pBmpOld);
    DeleteDC(dc);
    DeleteDC(dcMem);
    DeleteObject(_handleBMP);
    DeleteObject(pBmpOld);
    _handleBMP = NULL;

}
LeaveCriticalSection (&CriticalSection);
}
```