# gdi+ draws string inverted

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am trying to write text to a bitmap i am getting from an usb camera using directshow.
The problem is that the text is **mirror inverted upside-down** and i don't know why.

Here is the code that writes the text:

```
BITMAPINFOHEADER bih = m_videoInfo.bmiHeader;
Bitmap bmp(bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight, m_stride, m_pixFmt, pBuffer);
Graphics g(&bmp);

    if (this->introTimer->timeToDo())
    {

        RectF pos(10, 10, 100, 100);
        SolidBrush brush(Color::Black);

        Font font(FontFamily::GenericSerif(), 30);

        hr = g.DrawString(this->introText, -1, &font, pos, StringFormat::GenericDefault(), &brush);
        return hr;

    }
```

I am not sure if my code is the only thing that affects the drawing of the string. Maybe there is some configuration or something.

**Update**
I tried using a negative height as suggested by Hans Passant. The result is that the text is not written at all.

Comment: Inverted upside-down or left-to-right?  Upside-down is common enough, bitmaps tend to be stored with the scanlines in reverse.  Make the height negative.

Comment: it's inverted upside-down

Comment: Did you try to subtract the total height to the point you got?

Comment: @sergiol I don't understand your question, maybe you can describe what you mean in a formula

Comment: Did you try setting bih.biHeight to negative?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious thing to do would be to set the transformation on GDI+.

Essentially you need to invert the Y axis (though by doing this it would now draw off screen).  So you need to then translate it down by the window size.

Something like this:

```
 graphics.Transform = new Matrix2D( 1, 0,
                                    0, -1,
                                    0, -windowHeight );
```

Then draw as normal.

(Its worth noting I'm suggesting this without testing it.  The y translation may not be negative so try both!).

Answer (score 1):

The [scanlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969901.aspx) are stored upside down, with the first scan (scan 0) in memory being the bottommost scan in the image. This is another artifact of Presentation Manager compatibility. GDI automatically inverts the image during the Set and Get operations.

About the suggestion from Hans Passant, did you try negative height in position?
He suggests to use negative height in bih.

```
BITMAPINFOHEADER bih = m_videoInfo.bmiHeader;
bih.biHeight = -bih.biHeight;
Bitmap bmp(bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight, m_stride, m_pixFmt, pBuffer);
...
```

Also copying another solution from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022784/bitblt-drawing-bitmap-upside-down) if it helps

```
void BitmapControl::OnPaint()
{
EnterCriticalSection (&CriticalSection);

if (_handleBMP)
{

    CPaintDC dc(this);
    //dc.SetMapMode(MM_ISOTROPIC);
    dc.SetMapMode(MM_LOENGLISH);
    CDC dcMem;
    dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    dc.DPtoLP(&rect);

    CBitmap* pBmpOld = dcMem.SelectObject(CBitmap::FromHandle(_handleBMP));

    //tst
    dc.SetStretchBltMode(COLORONCOLOR);

    //BitBlt(dc,rect.left,-0,rect.Width(),rect.Height(),dcMem,rect.left,rect.top,SRCCOPY); //works with MM_TEXT but upsidedown
    BitBlt(dc,0,rect.bottom,rect.Width(),-rect.Height(),dcMem,0,0,SRCCOPY); //works with MM_LOENGLISH
    dcMem.SelectObject(pBmpOld);
    DeleteDC(dc);
    DeleteDC(dcMem);
    DeleteObject(_handleBMP);
    DeleteObject(pBmpOld);
    _handleBMP = NULL;

}
LeaveCriticalSection (&CriticalSection);
}
```

Comment: the result of using the negative height in my case is that the text is not printed at all.